# How to loop back to the start of a switch case statement C++

Tags: c++

i'm working on a program for a shop and need to ask the user if they want to buy items more than once. I've looked around but can't find anywhere or any code that helps me loop back to the start.

Here's what i have so far:

```
cout << "Welcome to Techi Toys!" << endl;


cout << "" << endl;
  cout << "Please select what product you would like to purchase: \n\n\n 1) iPhone \n 2) iPad Air \n 3) Sony Laptop \n 4) Kindle Fire \n 5) Xbox One \n 6) PS4 \n 7) Macbook Air \n 8) iPod Touch \n 9) DSLR Camera \n 10) Polaroid Camera \n" << endl;                                 
  cin >> choice; 

  switch(choice)
  {



case 1:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen iPhone 5S\n" << endl;
        price = 549;
        break;    
case 2:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen iPad Air\n" << endl;
        price = 399;
        break;           
case 3:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Sony Laptop\n" << endl;
        price = 798;         
        break;    
case 4:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Kindle Fire\n" << endl;
        price = 120;
        break;        
case 5:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Xbox One\n" << endl;
        price = 430;
        break;  
case 6:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen PS4\n" << endl;
        price = 350;
        break;  
case 7:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Macbook Air\n" << endl;
        price = 849;
        break;  
case 8:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen iPod Touch\n" << endl;
        price = 219;
        break;  
case 9:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen DSLR Camera\n" << endl;
        price = 519;
        break;  
case 10:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Polaroid Camera\n" << endl;
        price = 100;
        break; 


}                   
 //purchasing
 cout << "How many would you like to purchase?\n" << endl;
 cin >> quantity;
 cout << "\nThe total  is " << pound << ""<< price*quantity << endl;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you go a little deeper what you want to do?

Comment: @frlan I want the user to go through the switch case choosing what products they want and the quantity. I then want to ask them if they want to carry on shopping and if they select yes, loop back to the start of the switch case

Comment: Looks like you need a loop like `for` or `while`...

Comment: Put your selection logic in a loop and have an exit case to escape the loop.

Comment: You need to turn the problem around: instead of "how can I loop inside my input code", solve "how can I put my input code inside a loop".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ask the user if he wants to make more choices, you can put a loop around the switch, with the variable wantsMore = true. The loop would be

```
while (wantsMore)
{
    switch...
    // ask if user wants more, if no set wantsMore = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something as

```
do
{

  cout << "Please select what product you would like to purchase: \n\n\n 1) iPhone \n 2) iPad Air \n 3) Sony Laptop \n 4) Kindle Fire \n 5) Xbox One \n 6) PS4 \n 7) Macbook Air \n 8) iPod Touch \n 9) DSLR Camera \n 10) Polaroid Camera \n" << endl;                                 
  cin >> choice; 

  switch(choice)
  {



case 1:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen iPhone 5S\n" << endl;
        price = 549;
        break;    
case 2:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen iPad Air\n" << endl;
        price = 399;
        break;           
case 3:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Sony Laptop\n" << endl;
        price = 798;         
        break;    
case 4:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Kindle Fire\n" << endl;
        price = 120;
        break;        
case 5:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Xbox One\n" << endl;
        price = 430;
        break;  
case 6:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen PS4\n" << endl;
        price = 350;
        break;  
case 7:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Macbook Air\n" << endl;
        price = 849;
        break;  
case 8:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen iPod Touch\n" << endl;
        price = 219;
        break;  
case 9:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen DSLR Camera\n" << endl;
        price = 519;
        break;  
case 10:
        cout << "\nYou have chosen Polaroid Camera\n" << endl;
        price = 100;
        break; 


}                   
 //purchasing
 cout << "How many would you like to purchase?\n" << endl;
 cin >> quantity;
 cout << "\nThe total  is " << pound << ""<< price*quantity << endl;

std::cout << "One more (y/n)? ";
} while ( std::cin >> yes_no && yes_no == 'y' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need some means for the user to specify he want's to end his buy now...

So put your switch statement into a loop like this:

```
bool fTerminate = false;
do {
  // ... other stuff
  switch(choice) {
    case 0:
      fTerminate = true;
      break;

  // ...
  } // end of switch statement

  // purchasing / selecting the number of items ...
  // ...
} while( (!fTerminate) );

// ...
```